# How to pass this to a nested function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, oop, object

I was trying to execute something like this:

```
class A {
  functionA() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(this);
    }, 1000)
  }
}

const a = new A();
a.functionA();
```

But `this` always refers to the window object. I know that you could setup something like `var a = this`, but is there a more elegant way to pass this down from the object to the inner function?

Comment: `functionA() { setTimeout(console.log, 3000, this);` ... make a proper use of [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to meet the OP's expectation of coming up with ***a more elegant way*** I suggest the proper usage of [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Example) before thinking about any other approach ...

```js
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.delay = 3000;
  }
  functionA() {
    setTimeout(console.log, this.delay, this);
  }
}

const a = new A();
a.functionA();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an arrow function instead of a regular function to keep the `this` context:

```js
class A {
  functionA() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(this);
    }, 1000)
  }
}

const a = new A();
a.functionA();
```

Another way is to `.bind(this)` which will create a function with bounded `this` context:

```js
class A {
  functionA() {
    setTimeout((function() {
      console.log(this);
    }).bind(this), 1000)
  }
}

const a = new A();
a.functionA();
```

Answer (score 0):

Along with Sebastian's answer, another solution can be

```
class A {
  functionA() {
    const that = this
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(that);
    }, 1000)
  }
}

a = new A();
a.functionA();
```

Comment: ... scope or context ?.. The OP, btw, is aware of this solution. It was ask for _**a more elegant way**_.

Comment: context, let's switch back to our favorite 'that' so that there's no confusion